# Swift 5 UIScrollView adding background image

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, swift5

I'm trying to add a background image that will scroll with my vertical scrollView. Before adding the background image, my scrollView only scroll vertically, but after setting the background image, the scrollView can now scroll horizontally and vertically as if the background image's width is greater than the scrollview's width

```
let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
    let view = UIScrollView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.isDirectionalLockEnabled = true
    view.isScrollEnabled = true
    return view
}()

let backgroundIV: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "background"))
    imageView.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleToFill
    return imageView
}()
```

The function I use to setup my view

```
private func setupContent() {

    scrollViewHeight = viewHeight * 2

    [scrollView].forEach { view.addSubview($0) }
    scrollView.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, leading: view.leadingAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, trailing: view.trailingAnchor)
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: scrollViewHeight)

    [backgroundIV].forEach { scrollView.addSubview($0) }
    backgroundIV.anchor(top: scrollView.topAnchor, leading: scrollView.leadingAnchor, bottom: scrollView.bottomAnchor, trailing: scrollView.trailingAnchor, size: .init(width: 0, height: scrollViewHeight))

}
```

So how should i set my background image so that my scrollview won't scroll horizontally??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the right content sizes for your scrollView or adjust the content.

Set your imageView width equal to your scrollView's width. It will avoid scrollView horizontal scroll. 
Please find the below code for setting the widthAchor.

```
imageView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(scrollView.widthAnchor).active = true
```

Comment: Work like a charm

Answer (score 0):

After applying Vikram Parimi's answer and some further digging, there were two factors that effect my scrollview to become horizontal

- The characteristics of constraints between Scroll View and view tells us: the alignment and the size are not contradicted anymore, both of which must be defined to eliminate ambiguity. Which I found out from https://medium.com/@tingyishih/ios-scrollview-constraints-8d8140d329a0
- The other factor is that the bug only exist in iphone 11 pro max simulator and not iphone 8 simulator, which can be solve by using safeAreaLayoutGuide

```
 if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
      imageView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(scrollView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.widthAnchor).active = true
 } else {
      imageView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(scrollView.widthAnchor).active = true
 }
```